# Creating/Handling pathfinding large world waypoints in Blender

Tags: bezier-curves, performance

I am trying to create an importer/exporter script for an open world's game map. However, I am being constantly hit and set back by performance of blender.

I want to be able to create way points for car, with support for junctions (this would mean I need something that has more than 2 end points)

I have thought of using lines (path curves) for single line paths and for junctions I am thinking to calculate it mathematically at the point where 2 lines intersect. After importing about more than 3000 splines in a single curve object, blender have come to a slow crawl when it comes to edit mode, navigating in 3D view is quite fast as its only one object.

Is there any other way to do this? I am at loss now.
[image]
[image]

EDIT: I have also tried using armatures instead, as you can have many endpoints than a curve. However I found it crashing and unstable after hitting 6000 armature bones. And the selection of single bone is just painfully slow

Comment: Well my colleague has been through the same - creating navigation paths for a city roadmap which had to be C2 smooth. He ended up ditching blender entirely and coding a custom curve editor for the engine. It was simple and took 2 days to make, but in the end it saved a lot of time.

Comment: What about creating it as a mesh, then converting to a curve after?

Comment: @gandalf3 I did Alt-C, its very performant now. But I am not sure my users would want to edit paths as a mesh.

Also any ideas to go on adding in support of number of lanes in each lines? This is a path for cars.

Comment: @Jerryno I have no much idea about 3D programming in general. I can place objects in 3D but creating an 3D application from ground up seems way too much work for me.

Comment: @gandalf3 With mesh, I would also lose color for individual lines :(
Its not just city traffic. Its pedestrian traffic as well as the boat traffic and I would like to be able to visibly separate those path types.

Comment: I think blender reevaluates the entire curve whenever a vertex is moved. If you separate the disconnected curves into separate objects (P), does performance improve?

Comment: I think this question is either approaching the boundary of the scope of the site, because it is less about Blender than the mechanics of the game engine, or is too broad, because there are too many "open world" games for which you could be attempting to make the map many with their own game engines, and you've not provided any information on what game engine you want to use.

Comment: Are you trying to do this for the Blender Game engine?

Comment: @gandalf3 I have tried that as well. However I now have more than 3000 objects. And importing them and adding each curve is quite slow. This issue is quite common in general I think. 
Moreover blender consumes a lot of memory this way

Comment: @brasshat no this is nothing to do with the blender game engine at all. And nothing particular about any game engine at all. 

BTW, its nothing problematic about the script too, it' s just about blender when it comes to handling large number of objects/curve

Comment: If not done already, you could hide the parts you are not editing (H/Alt-H) and reduce the preview resolution to 1 (default is 12) in the properties panel. Also disable the normals display for curves in the N-Panel.